# Unsuccessful attempt to get a reference to a script and a set value in it

Tags: unity-game-engine

In a script called `MenuScript` (that is attached to a game object called `Menu Manager`) I set the following `enum` variable:

```
public trainingScenario selectedScenario;
```

to the following value `bluh`:

```
selectedScenario = trainingScenario.bluh;
```

In the `Start` method of another script called `SceneScript` (that is attached to a game object called `Scene Manager`) I use the following straightforward code to get a reference to `MenuScript` and use the set `enum` value, for example save it to file:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject menuManager = GameObject.Find("Menu Manager");
    MenuScript menuScript = menuManager.GetComponent<MenuScript>();
    Debug.Log( menuScript.selectedScenario );
}
```

But I get a `NullReferenceException`. At which step am I missing something or doing something wrong that I cannot access the value I am after?

**EDIT**:

Here are the scripts `MenuScript` and `SceneScript` respectively...

```
public enum trainingScenario
{
    None = 0,       // No scenario selected!
    CoopMimic,      // Cooperative with Mimicry
    CoopNoMimic,    // Cooperative without Mimicry
    ComptMimic,     // Competetive with Mimicry
    ComptNoMimic    // Competetive without Mimicry
}

public class MenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text confirmScenarioText;
    public trainingScenario selectedScenario;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad( this.gameObject );
        Debug.Log( this.gameObject.name );
    }

    void Start()
    {
        confirmScenarioText.text = "Select a Scenario and press Start Simulation";
        selectedScenario = trainingScenario.None;
    }

    public void confirmScenario( int index )
    {
        switch ( index )
        {
            case 1:
                    confirmScenarioText.text = "Cooperative with Mimicry scenario selected!";
                    selectedScenario = trainingScenario.CoopMimic;
                    break;
            case 2:
                    confirmScenarioText.text = "Cooperative without Mimicry scenario selected!";
                    selectedScenario = trainingScenario.CoopNoMimic;
                    break;
            case 3:
                    confirmScenarioText.text = "Competetive with Mimicry scenario selected!";
                    selectedScenario = trainingScenario.ComptMimic;
                    break;
            case 4:
                    confirmScenarioText.text = "Competetive without Mimicry scenario selected!";
                    selectedScenario = trainingScenario.ComptNoMimic;
                    break;
        }
    }

    public void startSimulation()
    {
        if ( selectedScenario == trainingScenario.None )
        {
            Debug.Log("Please choose a training scenario first!");
        }
        else
        {
            Application.LoadLevel ("mainScene");
        }
    }
}



public class SceneScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log( this.gameObject.name );
        GameObject menuManager = GameObject.Find("Menu Manager");
        MenuScript menuScript = menuManager.GetComponent<MenuScript>();
        Debug.Log( menuScript.selectedScenario );
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest use this pattern: http://unitypatterns.com/singletons/

Comment: +1 @Morrel because singleton patterns are good approaches for Managers once you will grant just one manager instance on game's lifecycle but this answer is more an improvement then a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your nullPoiter? can you provide your console out?

Try change your code to:

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject menuManager = GameObject.Find("Menu Manager");
    if(menuManager != null) {
        MenuScript menuScript = menuManager.GetComponent<MenuScript>();
        Debug.Log( menuScript.selectedScenario );
    }
}
```

**edited:**

To be clear on "path" that I mentioned on comment I'll link [`GameObject.Find()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) referece, there is an explanation about this.

**editted again:**
As you mentioned using two different scenes I recomend you to take a look at [`DontDestroyOnLoad()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

You can fast try this approach using DontDestroyOnLoad(this.**gameObject**) at your MenuScript.Awake();

Comment: The `nullPointer` is indicated at the middle line, which means your suggested code helps me remove the err msg, but I need to figure out why `menuScript` is null. The names are correct, though the objects are untagged. Could it be that they cannot be found without the tags that have the same names?

Comment: Find() will get by GameObject.Name and if object is active at search time. Probably Find() is returning null because your menuScript.gameobject.name is different of "Menu Manager" or is in some path with / and you are noth mapping it right.

Comment: You can easily debug to see your gameObject real name at runtime and adjust it on Find() method. Put a Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name) on your ScenariScript Awake() ;)

Comment: I tried this, and the name is indeed `Menu Manager`. I added the scripts if they help spot the problem. Thank you

Comment: Both scripts are in the same folder, and each game object is in the corresponding scene; i.e. the `Menu Manager` object is in the `menuScene` and the `Scene Manager` object is in the `mainScene`

Comment: could you try using `MenuManager` without whitespaces? Your script looks correct, but we can't see the GameObjects in Unity itself, make sure the `MenuManager` is active and tags are properly assigned (if you're using them)

Comment: So if you are using 2 different unity scenes and your objects are separated each per scene? You need to see DonDestroyOnLoad() function because unity doesn't persist game objects between scenes if you don't explicit tell it.

Comment: @Frohlich:  Yes, that is correct. I did not know about `DonDestroyOnLoad()`. I will try it right away...

Comment: Is the `Start` function of the initial `MenuScript` the right place to call `DontDestroyOnLoad(this);` to preserve the `Menu Manager` game object that has the script attached to it? It is not making a difference...

Comment: Sorry, as you need to persist the GameObject to use in Find you need DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject), i'll adjust on answer ;)

Comment: Thank you!  I have added `DontDestroyOnLoad( this.gameObject );` to the `MenuScript` that is attached to the `Menu Manager` game object, so when I load a new scene (with the `Scene Manager` game object and `SceneScript` attached to it) it should be able to access the `selectedScenario` value then. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the NullPointer trying to find the GameObject, try assigning the tag `Menu Manager` to the Menu Manager and use `GameObject.FindWithTag("Menu Manager")` instead.
Remember, "Menu Manager" **must** be active to be found with Find() or FindWithTag()

===

If the NullPointer is when you try to get the script, this might be the cause:

`MenuScript.Start()` is running before `SceneScript.Start()`. (this order is a bit unpredictable)

You could use the `MenuScript.Awake()` method to assign the `bluh` because it will always run before all `Start()` methods in any script.

Comment: It probably is true if he is not setting the value on inspector and as he doesn't provide entire code from SceneScript I guess he's using inspector to set selectScenario on SceneScript, am I right? I cant access Unity right now to test but I'm almost sure that setting on inspector will apply before Start() time.

Comment: Thank you, but the `blah` value is set in a different function in the `MenuScript` and not in the `Start` so by the time I move on to the next scene, the value is definitely set...

Comment: based on your comment, see if what I added to the answer helps you

Comment: @cahen Find() and FindWithTag() are different and both valid methods to find GameObjects...

Comment: @Frohlich you're right in both comments. And probably we need to see more of the code

Comment: I added the scripts if they help spot the problem. Thank you

Comment: @cahen: You say  "Menu Manager" must be active to be found with Find() or FindWithTag() but when I press a GUI button to load the next scene, the menu scene will no longer be active then. Right?

Comment: all GameObjects are destroyed when changing scenes, unless you explicitly use `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` as mentioned by @Frohlich. You have to decide between not destroying it or creating a new one in the next scene

Comment: this is why I commented that using singleton for Managers is a good approach because usually you want managers to live between scenes and maintaining last set of values and you'll have just one manager per scope (one LevelManager, one ScoreManager, etc...) so you create your singleton with DontDestroyOnLoad() flag and can use this granting no duplication until you decide to kill it manually.

Comment: The code with all the DontDestroy suggestion is in the question now, but that is not preserving the object, or I am doing something else wrong...

Comment: If I wanted to use `DontDestroyOnLoad( this.confirmScenario );` where should I put it: before `switch`, afterward, etc...? I get overloading errors...